# Can Gohan transform to Super Saiyan in Mystic form?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-z

In DBZ, we see that the Elder Kai fully awakens the dormant power of Gohan. In this state Gohan can match Buu in his unfused form. But after Buu absorbs Piccolo and Gotenks, why doesn't Gohan go Super?

Is there any reason that Gohan couldn't transform to Super Saiyan form after the awakening?

Edit 1: Removed the transformation in GT from consideration because DBZ and GT are seperate canons.

Edit 2: Dragon Ball Super has canon continuity to DBZ and I've heard talks of Ultimate Gohan in it. Has more information been provided on Gohan's transformation in DBS? Please Note: Yet to see DBS beyond the intial movies.

Answer (score 8):

I think I found a possible answer, because I had a similar question.

In [Gohan](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Gohan) article on Dragon Ball Wiki.

> However, amazed at realizing that
>   some of his power really was unlocked, Gohan apologizes to Old Kai,
>   and resumes the ritual. **After some time, the ritual is finally
>   completed and Gohan is told to power up like he does for the Super
>   Saiyan transformation; however, when he does, his appearance does not
>   change, but his power and strength gain an awesome increase.**

So it seems when Gohan got "Mystic Gohan", even though he increased his power, his appearance didn't change. So he couldn't transform in any other Saiyan form than the normal form, but he was still getting stronger.

I'm not sure if he is able to change, but the fact is, there would be no difference. He already got all his power in his normal form, without a change.

Comment: This seems like a good plausible explanation. I also did some reading of my own. It seems that when Gohan powers up for Mystic form, his eyes turn green for a moment. The reason of his strength is explained as same as the time they fought Cell. He doesn't waste energy transforming. Essentially he is at the same level as a SS3 without wasting any energy transforming as Goku did. He powered up but didn't transform.

Comment: @Arcane Chapter 497 seems to confirm this. Gohan is told to transform into a SS, but even though he gathers massive amounts of energy, he doesn't physically change. If this series was ongoing I would have expected Goku's words to be foreshadowing something great when he said *I wonder if you can surpass this too..*, but we never really saw any evidence of this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. His power was fully awaken and so he had no need to transform into super Saiyan. He could go super but he didn't know that Buu could absorb people and their power level.

When he is in mystic form his full power was awaken and he had the same power as he did as super Saiyan. so his base power was risen. He can still transform into a SS or SS2 at any point he wants to. Its just the fact that he has the same power level and so he doesn't see the point to.

A good sight for you to look at the goes more in detail is [Dragonball wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Why_can't_Ultimate_Gohan_go_ssj%3F)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand the point you're trying to make here. "He could go super but he didnt know that buu could absorb people and thier power level." I am asking why doesn't he go Super AFTER Buu absorbs Gotenks and Piccollo. Also if the base power of Gohan has risen, it seems logical to assume that his power in Super Saiyan should also rise accordsingly?

Comment: Also the link you gave also gives several conflicting answers with no clear canon proof and mostly theorized answers. I haven't found a clear answer as of yet

Comment: Gohan doesn't go super after buu abosrbs gotenks and piccollo beacuse at the very moment since his base power has risen the power needed to go to ss was a lot more and he didn't have that power yet.

Comment: Getting your information from the comments on a wiki page is not an accurate way to provide information to others.

Comment: Not a right answer, the right answer was giving in DBS in can be seen here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8G4shXF9bo0

Comment: @Pablo after watching that you are correct it does show this in DBS. Thanks for the update. Always good to learn something new

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually no.  Gohan's Mystic Powerup IS his Super Saiyan transformation which is why elder Kai tells him to powerup as if he were transforming.

Answer (score 1):

In Dragon Ball Super when training with Piccolo Gohan powered up to super saiyan 2, and then he made a final effort and transformed into mystic form , passing from super saiyan 2 to mystic form in a gradual change, as a next stage, so no, now with Dragon Ball Super the answer is clear, he can't transform into super saiyan when in mystic form because it's another stage of power. You can see it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8G4shXF9bo0

Answer (score 0):

According to Dragon Ball Wiki, Daizenshuu 2 commented on the possibility of [Gohan](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Gohan#Power) becoming a Super Saiyan:

> Daizenshuu 2 states that Ultimate Gohan is still capable of becoming a Super Saiyan, but even without utilising the form he surpasses Super Saiyan 3 Gotenks in power, if Ultimate Gohan was to become a Super Saiyan his power would likely rise to levels above even Super Buu (Gohan, Piccolo, Goten, and Trunks absorbed).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Gohan's Mystic Power-Up actually made it so his ki transformed to that of a Kai, but doing so made it so that his appearance doesn't change when he goes Super Saiyan.

When he fought Super Buu, he was actually a Super Saiyan 2 charged by Kai energy, but the Kai powers he got from his Mystic training made his Super Saiyan lose the aura and hair and eye color.

Apparently that Kai training has worn off by the events of Battle of the Gods, Resurrection F and Dragon Ball Super because he went back to not training.

Answer (score 0):

It makes perfect sense that Ultimate Gohan (the official name for the "form") can go Super Saiyan. Whenever Gohan had sudden outburst of rage and power he utilized and unleashed very small portions of his full power, the greatest example of this was him transforming into and SSJ2 against Perfect Cell.

The Super Saiyan forms are only multipliers, and are NOT set levels of power. Ultimate Gohan is just Gohan with his potential unlocked, he can't get stronger than that naturally, but utilizing forms and skills like the Kaio-ken, and Super Saiyan forms would multiply his power.

For further proof, the Daizenshuu 2 clearly states that Ultimate Gohan can go Super Saiyan, and doing that would make him even stronger that Buuhan.